# SoapUI reference attached file to edit contents?

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to modify the values of an attachment to a SOAP Request to correspond to values that I'm getting from a DataSource. I want to do this with a groovy script.  I'm looking for a way to reference the attachment file path so I can edit the file itself but I'm having no luck finding that. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Check out this question on SO. OP is doing the same thing you want to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066049/attaching-file-in-soapui-with-groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after looking at the API for a long time

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.RequestFileAttachment
def xmlFile = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("YOUR TEST STEP NAME").testRequest.getAttachmentAt(0).getUrl()
```

xmlFile will contain the full path of the attached file. Wanted to post this here in case someone else was looking for a quick way.